# When using NuxtLink, how do you perform a store mutation before navigation?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, vue-router

I am trying to update a store value before the router kicks in an navigates to the desired route.

This is my current code which is not working:

```html
<NuxtLink :to="`/posts/${post.slug}`" @click="setPost(post)">
  {{ post.title.rendered }}
</NuxtLink>
```

If I manually trigger the mutation by adding a button like so:

```html
<button @click="setPost(post)">{{ post.title.rendered }}</button>
```

and then hit the NuxtLink, everything works as expected, but obviously this isn't correct.

How do I ensure that a store mutation is executed before going to the `/posts/` page?

Thank you.

Comment: You can either use `beforeRouteLeave` hook in your page/component to do the mutation before leaving, or a middleware.

Comment: @MojtabaBarari thank you! this is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

A link should be a navigation, not doing something else if following the semantics of HTML.

You can then have some logic when leaving or entering specific pages thanks to Vue router guards: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html

---

If you want to trigger a vue action (recommended over a vue mutation [as stated in the documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/#what-is-a-state-management-pattern)), you can totally call `setPost(post)` via **a button** and then, do a `$router.push('/posts ....')` with your variables as shown in the documentation: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-push-location-oncomplete-onabort